# Chart.js data from multiple queries

Tags: php, mysqli, chart.js

I am trying to plot a chart using Chart.JS with data from multiple MySql queries. However, when I tried loading it, the graph only display one month. Any idea how I can do this? Thank you. Hope you can help me

Here's the code for the queries:

```
 //Query for graph
      
  $applied_query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(id) as 'count', monthname(date_created) as 'month' FROM data.application WHERE status ='APPLIED' AND year(date_created)= year(curdate()) GROUP BY month");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($applied_query)){
            $month[] = $row["month"];
            $countApplied = $row['count'];
    }

  $verified_query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(id) as 'count', monthname(date_verified) as 'month' FROM data.application WHERE status ='VERIFIED' AND year(date_verified)= year(curdate()) GROUP BY month");

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($verified_query)){
            $month[] = $row["month"];
            $countVerified = $row['count'];
    }


  $approved_query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(id) as 'count', monthname(date_approved) as 'month' FROM data.application WHERE status ='APPROVED' AND year(date_approved)= year(curdate()) GROUP BY month");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($approved_query)){
            $month[] = $row["month"];
            $countApproved = $row['count'];
    }


  $released_query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(id) as 'count', monthname(date_released) as 'month' FROM data.application WHERE status ='RELEASED' AND year(date_released)= year(curdate()) GROUP BY month");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($released_query)){
            $month[] = $row["month"];
            $countReleased = $row['count'];
    }
```

And here's the code for the graph.

```
<!-- Bar Chart -->
   <canvas id="barChart" style="max-height: 400px;"></canvas>
    <script>
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      new Chart(document.querySelector('#barChart'), {
       type: 'bar',
       data: {
        labels: <?php echo json_encode($month); ?>,
        datasets: [{
         label: 'Applied',
         data: <?php echo json_encode($countApplied); ?>,
         backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.3)'
         ],
         borderColor: [
          'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
         ],
         borderWidth: 1,
        }, {
        label: 'Verified',
         data: <?php echo json_encode($countVerified); ?>,
         backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.3)'
         ],
         borderColor: [
          'rgb(54, 162, 235)'
         ],
         borderWidth: 1
        }, {
         label: 'Approved',
         data: <?php echo json_encode($countApproved); ?>,
         backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(60, 179, 113, 0.3)'
         ],
         borderColor: [
          'rgb(60, 179, 113)'
         ],
         borderWidth: 1
        }, {
         label: 'Released',
         data: <?php echo json_encode($countReleased); ?>,
         backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.3)'
         ],
         borderColor: [
          'rgb(255, 159, 64)'
         ],
         borderWidth: 1
        }]
       },
       options: {
        scales: {
         yAxes: [{
          ticks:{
           beginAtZero: true
          }
         }]
        }
       }
      });
     });
    </script>
<!-- End Bar CHart -->
```

The output should look like [image: this].

Comment: Check what JavaScript code you _would_ need to create that kind of diagram, and then compare it with the structure your PHP code produces.

Answer (score 0):

save your data to array like `$month`, example `$countApplied = $row['count']` change to `$countApplied[] = $row['count']`;

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($applied_query)){
  $month[] = $row["month"];
  $countApplied[] = $row['count'];
}
```